# Biblatex: How to have an ampersand in \textcite when there are two authors

Tags: biblatex, apa-style, apa7

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ellipsis}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber, sortlocale=de]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{german}{german-apa}
\addbibresource{Literatur.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{literatur.bib}

@article{MartinsonBerridge2015,
  title = {Successful {{Aging}} and {{Its Discontents}}: {{A Systematic Review}} of the {{Social Gerontology Literature}}},
  shorttitle = {Successful {{Aging}} and {{Its Discontents}}},
  author = {Martinson, Marty and Berridge, Clara},
  date = {2015-02}
}

\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}

„hello“ \parencite[p. 12]{MartinsonBerridge2015}

\textcite{MartinsonBerridge2015} say,
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

It spits out

> „hello“ (Martinson & Berridge, 2015, p. 12)
>
> Martinson und Berridge (2015) says,

But i would like it to spit out:

> „hello“ (Martinson & Berridge, 2015, p. 12)
>
> Martinson & Berridge (2015) say,

So how can i change the `\textcite` to also put an ampersand there instead of `und` (which is `and` in german).

I am confused about it in the first place, since the ampersand is needed in both cases to fit the APA-guidelines, I don't know why it even shows that inconsistency there.

Comment: This is the current APA 7th edition style. See https://apastyle.apa.org/instructional-aids/creating-reference-list.pdf

Comment: You wrote, "i dont know why it even shows that inconsistency." It's not an inconsistency but a feature: The powers-that-be at the APA have declared that `&` should be used as the name connector in parenthetic-style citation call-outs, but that `and` (or `und`) should be used as the connector in textual-style citation call-outs. Don't ask.

Comment: And in fact, one can argue that it's a sensible choice, since in text citations are part of the text, and use of abbreviations is usually discouraged in texts generally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Alan says in the comments, this is correct APA style (see for example https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/citations/basic-principles/author-date). If you want to change the output of `\textcite` regardless, you can try something like the following

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareDelimAlias[textcite]{finalnamedelim}[parencite]{finalnamedelim}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{MartinsonBerridge2015,
  title    = {Successful Aging and Its Discontents},
  subtitle = {A Systematic Review of the Social Gerontology Literature},
  author   = {Martinson, Marty and Berridge, Clara},
  date     = {2015-02},
  journal  = {Gerontologist},
  volume   = {55},
  pages    = {58-69},
  doi      = {10.1093/geront/gnu037},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
\enquote{hello} \parencite[12]{MartinsonBerridge2015}

\textcite{MartinsonBerridge2015} say

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: „hello“ (Martinson & Berridge, 2015, S. 12) Martinson & Berridge (2015) say]

This is the shortest way to change just `\textcite`. A conceptually slightly more satisfying, but longer solution, that changes the output of all cite commands to use the ampersand, would be to say

```
\DeclareDelimFormat*{finalnamedelim}
  {\ifnum\value{liststop}>2 \finalandcomma\fi\addspace\&\space}
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib,biblist]{finalnamedelim}{%
  \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}>\maxprtauth}
    {}
    {\ifthenelse{\value{liststop}>2}
       {\finalandcomma\addspace\&\space}
       {\addspace\&\space}}}
```

instead.